# Can't undelete a Contact record

Tags: undelete

I can't undelete a contact record that was deleted earlier today.  I get the following error.  I can, however, delete & undelete other contact records.  This is on a Professional version of Salesforce so I can't use data loader.  The structure of the object has not been changed since the record was deleted.  It has only bee deleted for a few hours.  There aren't any Contact validation rules or process builder/flows that should cause a problem.

Unable to undelete 1 of the record(s) because:
The record may have already been undeleted or removed from the Recycle Bin
The record may have been orphaned by the deletion of the custom object
You may no longer have access to undelete the record(s)
A data integrity rule or Apex trigger would fail if the record was undeleted

Comment: Is the Account of the contact deleted?

Comment: I just confirmed that the account is still there.

Comment: Check the debug logs to see if it gives to a but more information (shortly before where it throws that error you might find what is causing it)

Comment: I turned on debug.  I don't see any errors.  Should I have seen an error?

Comment: Sometimes a roll-up-summary field in combination with a formula field causes this kind of error

Comment: I do have a formula field that references rollup fields.  I just made the formula field just be an empty string.  The undelete still is not working.  What do I need to do to get around the problem?